# Using Backbone.js for a static-content, JavaScript-heavy site?

Tags: javascript, static, backbone.js, web

I'm building a site for a client that is comprised all of static content, meaning it's not a web app in the sense that it won't involve any user interaction and manipulation of data on the site itself.

With that being said, the UI is quite complex and will certainly end up being very JavaScript-heavy, so I wanted to utilize a JS framework.

I've done a bunch of research and found plenty of examples of Backbone.js being used for highly-interactive web apps, also with extensive UI, but I was wondering if it would be a good choice for my situation as well. It appears it still would be, given my UI requirements, but I'm wondering I'd other people have had success using it in instances similar to mine.

And if it isn't a good fit, are there any other recommendations?

Comment: Backbone's core feature is managing data models client-side and using views and events to maintain the DOM as models change. It's not really a UI framework. What benefits do you think you'd get from using Backbone on a static site?

Comment: I suppose I need to provide some clarifications. So the content is static in the sense that there won't be any users manipulating the data through the site itself. It will all be managed through a CMS. It's still based around different data models, though, and the backend will surely be built on an MVC framework. I thought I could benefit from using Backbone  to keep the front-end JavaScript for the various models in good order, as there will be a great deal of DOM interaction and manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently written a one page web app with no server side functionality using the great [backbone boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate).

Regardless of having explicit models from the server to manage sync, you can still apply the methodology to UI. For example an app that I have been working on recently had some very complex functionality/interactions with images. It was extremely useful model the images (with some meta data such as dimensions, captions etc etc) with Backbone, save them in a collection and tie the model/collection to my Backbone views. It makes the UI logic really easy to maintain, update, reuse and unit test.

With the boilerplate you also get a great build process, linting and some pointers for unit testing etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your site doesn't include heavy user interaction, DOM updates and non postback repaints (i.e Ajax + DOM manipulation), but just content managed via CMS, a client side MV* framework is not the right tool. Most CMSs (Drupal, Wordpress) already include a predefined structure as well as tempting/theming approaches in the server side that doesn't necessarily match with what Backbonejs, Angular etc offers. In a nutshell: If you project is a Web App, a MV* Front-end framework makes sense. If it is a content site, go for other approach tied to what your selected CMS offers.